# How to check if immediate previous run failed or not?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, perl

I have a perl script that runs and does some checks.
In some cases that script fails and stops processing and in others completes.
What I would like to do is to be able to check if the script run within 1 minute and if the run was successful somehow then exit.
I thought about saving some file or checking $?, as an indication but I thought there may be exist some standard clean approach for this.
Would like a solution that would work for both linux and mac

Comment: You can catch all exceptions and write result somewhere.

Comment: @Сухой27: I would like to somehow indicate that the run was success if the next run is under 1 min

Comment: I don't believe there is a standard approach to such scenario.

Comment: I'd try using the `timeout` command then checking `$?`, or just run it in an `if` to test success if you don't care about the actual exit code.

Comment: Define "successful". If the run meets the criteria, create a file as the script's final action, else don't. When the script next runs, check if the file exists and was created (modified) within the time desired. Remove the file at the beginning of the run if it's present.

Comment: RELATED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757338/determine-time-elapsed-since-last-timestamp

Comment: Do you need this from another script, which runs the script that does checks (which is what my answer is about) -- or from the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

You could see if you script has ended after a minute by trying something like this :

```
sleep 60
ps -ae | grep yourScript.name
```

This has to be executed at the same time as your script(s). If it returns nothing, that means your script isn't running anymore, aka has ended.

For the final result, you could make your perl script write into a specific log file, and check the end of this log file if the `ps -ae | grep yourScript.name` returned nothing.

Hope it helped !