# Determine time elapsed since last timestamp

Tags: perl

I would like to write to a file a timestamp and then be able to determine if the current time is < 1 min from that timestamp.
Using:

```
open my $fh, '>', '~/.time_from_run';  
my $timestamp = localtime(time);    
print $fh $timestamp;  
close $fh;
```

prints out a string. What is the best way for this?

Comment: Why not write just `time` into the file?

Comment: Just use `time`, not `localtime`, subtract the two numbers and divide by 60 to get minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to write the output from `time()` rather than `localtime()` (incidentally, `localtime(time)` is pointless - if you omit the parameter to `localtime()`, it will use `time()` as a default). That will give you the number of seconds since the start of 1970 (which is a very big number - currently 1503061737). You can then read that number back and compare it with the current value of `time()`.

The (slight) downside to this approach is that the numbers you get back from `time()` aren't easily understandable by humans. If you will want to read and understand the values in `.time_from_run` then you could compromise and write the timestamp in an easily understood format (ISO-8601 is the obvious choice.

```
use Time::Piece;

open my $fh, '>', '~/.time_from_run' or die $!;

print $fh localtime->datatime;
```

You can then read and compare your time like this:

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

open my $fh, '<', '~/.time_from_run' or die !$;

chomp(my $then_str) = <$fh>;

my $then = Time::Piece->strptime('%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S', $then_str);

if (localtime - $then < ONE_MINUTE) {
  print "Elapsed time is less than a minute\n";
}
```

Comment: `time` gives an epoch right? So I could use the command line to figure out what it is right?

Comment: Sure. `date -d @1503061737` gives `Fri 18 Aug 14:08:57 BST 2017`

Comment: RELATED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757088/how-to-check-if-immediate-previous-run-failed-or-not